# Connect to google cloud instance fail

Tags: http, google-app-engine, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to connect to google cloud instance from my ios app project. But I stuck in connecting to google cloud. Watched this tutorial but is outdated. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxZvofAvgHQ&t=179s

**Here is the code I will use in my app**

```
Alamofire.request("http://external_ip:80/test.php", method: .post, parameters: ["test": String(1)]).responseString { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        print(response.result)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**Steps to try connecting to google cloud.**

1. use safari to connect https://external_ip:80

`Failed to open page`

2. `gcloud beta compute firewall-rules list`

`NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                        DENY
default-allow-http      default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80
default-allow-https     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:065535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22
rule-allow-tcp-80       default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80`

3. `gcloud compute instances list`

`NAME    ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
outbuy  asia-east1-a  f1-micro                   internal_ip   external_ip  RUNNING`

4. `gcloud compute ssh <my_pj>` then `sudo nc -l -vv -p 80`

nc: listen: Address already in use

5. Try both solutions in here [Can't connect to port 80 on Google Cloud Compute instance despite firewall rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620723/cant-connect-to-port-80-on-google-cloud-compute-instance-despite-firewall-rule)

Added this

```
// On your workstation:
SUBNETWORK_URI=$(gcloud compute instances describe ${COS_INSTANCE_NAME} | grep -w 'subnetwork:' | awk '{ print $2 }')
SUBNET_PREFIX=$(gcloud compute networks subnets describe ${SUBNETWORK_URI} | grep -w 'ipCidrRange:' | awk '{ print $2 }')
// On your Container-Optimized OS instance:
sudo iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp -s ${SUBNET_PREFIX} -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -w -A INPUT -p udp -s ${SUBNET_PREFIX} -j ACCEPT
```

And

```
// Add a new tag based firewall rule to allow ingress tcp:80
gcloud compute firewall-rules create rule-allow-tcp-80 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags allow-tcp-80 --allow tcp:80
// Add the allow-tcp-80 target tag to the VM ssrf3
gcloud compute instances add-tags ssrf3 --tags allow-tcp-80
```

Still no change.

Any suggestion?

Comment: could you try Safari with HTTP (not HTTP)? Also, could try `wget` for some more insight into what actually fails.

Comment: Oh damn. Get a "It works" page. Thanks