# Cannot access IP:8080

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I simply followed this tutorial without NGINX.

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-jenkins-on-centos-7

After that, I can't view the Jenkins instance on my IP:8080.

What could be causing this? Is it a Google thing?

I installed net-tools to help verify, but I'm fairly new at this.

Running `systemctl status jenkins` gives me this.

```
Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-12-22 06:47:17 UTC; 1h 32min ago
```

Runing `ps -ef | grep jenkins` gives me this.

```
jenkins   2251     1 41 08:26 ?        00:00:09 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemo
nized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --
logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8080 --ht
tpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 --accessLoggerCl
assName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLo
gger.file=/var/log/jenkins/access_log
kevinca+  2319  1035  0 08:26 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto jenkins
```

Running `netstat -ant` gives me this.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0     64 10.148.0.3:22           74.125.73.161:34826     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.148.0.3:49658        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.148.0.3:49656        169.254.169.254:80      CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 10.148.0.3:49664        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.148.0.3:49662        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Is the Jenkins Service running? "ps -ef | grep jenkins"

Comment: `lsof -i:8080`? What is the result? You also need allow 8080 on VM windows firwall and Google Cloud firewall.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT lsof -i:808 doesn't output anything.

Comment: 808 or 8080? If yes 8080, it seems your service is not listening on 8080. `netstat -ant`

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Yes, I meant 8080. I updated my post for the netstat.

Comment: @hannes91 Hi, I updated my post for the result.

Comment: @Kevin It only listens on `127.0.0.1`. You could not access it outside VM. Try modify it to "0.0.0.0" or VM's private IP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161794/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-kevin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should let jenkins listen on `0.0.0.0` or VM's private IP. `127.0.0.1` is a loop IP address, it only works inside VM.

Secondly, Google Cloud VM also have a firewall, you need  add a firwall rule on it, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620723/cant-connect-to-port-80-on-google-cloud-compute-instance-despite-firewall-rule).