# Google Cloud Compute Engine refusing connections despite firewall rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a VNC server on my GCE instance running debian. Normally I connect over SSH, but I need a graphical interface for some other use cases. I have a very basic firewall rule that looks like this [image]

But when I use netcat to check the external IP on port 5901 I get that the connection is refused. Checking a port like 22 works, but none of the other ones let me connect. Am I missing a step here?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620723/cant-connect-to-port-80-on-google-cloud-compute-instance-despite-firewall-rule

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The most common problem related to your issue is that the application / server is configured for `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, which means accept connections only on the local machine. You need to bind with `0.0.0.0` which means listen on all available networks.

When connecting from the public network (outside your system) `Connection refused` means that nobody is listening. This is not a firewall rule issue as the error message indicates that the connection is not being blocked (no response) versus refused (permission denied).

Connect to your instance via SSH. Then run this command: `netstat -a`. Look for a line that says `LISTENING` on your port number. Then look at the IP address. If it shows `127.0.0.1`, this is your problem. If you do not see your port number in `LISTENING` state, then you do not have a process listening on that port.

Comment: This is what I see https://imgur.com/a/KiMIN5B

running netcat localhost 5901 also shows a process listening there

Comment: Port 5901 is listening on localhost. This means that you can only connect to this port from inside the machine. You will need to change the software to listen on `0.0.0.0`. `localhost` translates to `127.0.0.1`. This address is a private address which means `my-system`. Every computer with a TCP/IP stack has 127.0.0.1 as its internal `loopback` address.

Comment: Sorry if this is unrelated, but If i'm trying to start a VNC server, do you know how to go about doing that?

Comment: Different topic. Create a new question.

Comment: @JohnHanley 
I am having the same Problem. I created a Nodejs Local Server on Port 8080 in Google Compute Engine Instance. I am able to connect to this only from 127.0.0.1(localhost) inside the Server.

Not able to connect to that PORT  outside that server from other system . Can anyone help please. I want to connect to that PORT to get JSON response on that PORt.

Despite my Local Server is running I am not able to my PORT Number in netstat -a 



* I have gone through Firewall Settings but I dont think it is a Firewall Rule Issue.

Comment: @PiyushAggarwal - Create a question.

Comment: For the uninitiated how does one bind to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: @Magoo - depends on the code/library. Create a new question. Typically you specify `0.0.0.0`. Note you are not binding to that address, you are listening on all network interfaces. `0.0.0.0` is not a real/valid address in the scope of IP addressing.

Comment: Done and thanks... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385192/python-docker-image-refusing-connection

Comment: How to solve this issue?  Doesn't seem like it was solved for the OP.  How do you fix the issue.  Seems like answer is only explaining the issue.