# Instance is running but ip shows nothing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, instance

I have a google cloud platform, with a VM instance and a SQL. Today they got suspended because the free trial ended. I restarted them both and now they are running. But when i try to go to the ip of the VM instance in my browser, it says This site can’t be reached and "refused to connect". Note that i know nothing about Google Cloud and instances, i just need to have my moodle up and running again.

I tried securing that it allowed http and https in the console. (Ref to [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/basic-webserver-apache#troubleshooting))
The external DNS setting is correct.
And i checked if it was on localhost (ref to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689033/google-cloud-compute-engine-refusing-connections-despite-firewall-rule/53689160))

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using an ephemeral external IP address, that address has been release when the instance was stopped.
If you were using a static external IP address, that address was also released the moment your trial expired, hence reserved IPs generate costs.

When your re-started the instance, probably it received a new IP address.

Check for the external IP address that the instance is currently using and try to use it.

You can see the instances running in your project here: https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

Answer (score 0):

The resources you created during the trial are stopped and If you upgrade within 30 days of the end of the trial, you can restore the resources you created during the trial.

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end

Answer (score 0):

What happened is that all resources you created during the trial were stopped.

As Neo mentioned, if you didn’t have your external IP address reserved, the IP was released when the instances were stopped and when you started your instances again, GCP provided a new External IP.

You can check what External IP you have on the [External IP addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses?_ga=2.238285376.1137955818.1597064302-638966553.1591892739), and try to access your moodle through this new IP.

To avoid this problem in the future you can promote your ephemeral external IP address, you can use this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) as reference or follow the next steps:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the **[External IP addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses?_ga=2.238285376.1137955818.1597064302-638966553.1591892739)** page.
2. In the **Type** column, change the address type to **Static** for the IP address you want to promote.
3. Provide a name for the new static IP address and click **Reserve**.

In this way, the next time you stop your instance you will keep your IP.

Nevertheless, you are **not** charged for static external IP addresses that are assigned to forwarding rules.

Also you can consult the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#ipaddress) for External IP address pricing, in which the documentation provides you pricing for static and ephemeral external IP addresses.