# I can't running django on port 80

Tags: python, django, web, web-applications, google-compute-engine

I can't running django in my website server at port 80... because It gives me that port is already in use?? may I know what's the problem exactly?

this is the link for my website It only gives me a html page (zabarjad.co).

but when I type in command line to run django this is what happen:

```
aziz@zabarjad-djangostack-vm:/var/www/zabarjadprod$ sudo python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 06, 2021 - 17:40:17
Django version 2.2.15, using settings 'zabarjadprod.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:80/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That port is already in use.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aziz, there is something running at port 80 on your system. check for other services and servers installed on your system and shut down the on the said port.

Comment: And how to find what exactly running... cause It's been now 1 month and can't find anything to help me

Comment: what os do you use?

Comment: I'm using linux debian

Comment: read this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/

Comment: I find this:
```tcp6 0  0 :::80   :::*   LISTEN  7054/apache2 ``` may I know what it mean?

Comment: you have an apache server running. apache servers run at port 80 by default.

Comment: and how can I disable it to run my new app that I build

Comment: I just want to run ```python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80``` but It refuse and give me this ```Error: That port is already in use.``` And I don't know where exactly It used or how can I change IT... Briefly The only thing I want to do is make my website run normally but It's not rendering codes as you see here (zabarjad.co)

Comment: Kill 7054 should do it.

Comment: Is there any update command or something like this to type so it run properly? cause I did the "kill" command and It doesn't give me the previous error anymore! and that's good thanks! but still not rendering the page with django (zabarjad.co)

Comment: If it is not rendering your pages, then there must be an error somewhere. Check your console

Comment: Mr @Chymdy !! thanks a lot you saved me! The "kill" command solve the issue after 1 month dealing with it!!! and I got tired and start to think to delete everything!! thaaanks again and again!

Answer (score 0):

It means there is some other program on your computer running on port `80`. I personally have the following shortcut in my `~/.bash_profile` to analyze these sort of things:

```
alias ports="sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P"
```

If you run it by itself, you should see something along the lines of (assuming you are running MacOS. If not Google, how to find the ports of running processes for your machine):

[image]

On the right side, the ports of each process is shown. You can then do `kill {PID}` (e.g. `kill 4749` would kill my Spotify instance) to kill the process running on port 80 (make sure it's something you aren't actually using).

---

I should add, however, than there are very few times that you might want to use port `80` locally. It's better to use `8080` or something else, and only on deployment use `80`.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say that I use "Google compute engine" so I use virtual machine on google servers... Is this solution work the same?

Comment: Likely another service is already running on the VM on port 80. Regardless, I think it's worth understanding that Django _does not recommend running the server in production with `manage.py`_. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620723/cant-connect-to-port-80-on-google-cloud-compute-instance-despite-firewall-rule) might help regarding port 80 being occupied. If you are deploying for production, check the docs on it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/) - it's not a solution for this "port 80 fiasco," but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: I just want to run ```python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80``` but It refuse and give me this ```Error: That port is already in use.``` And I don't know where exactly It used or how can I change IT... Briefly The only thing I want to do is make my website run normally but It's not rendering codes as you see here (zabarjad.co)

Comment: Again - in such case port 80 is being used within the VM. In the previous comment above I linked a SO question that might help.